# C++ LinkedList Queue Implementation and Destructor Error:"Aborted (Core Dumped)"

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I'm trying to learn about C++ and I am having issues with memory management and the concept of destructors. I have tried to write a Queue implementation using Linked Lists, and I am receiving "Aborted (Core Dumped)" error messages when I try to delete my linked list nodes in my destructor method (bolded). If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know!

Here's the code for my destructor method:

```
template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue(){
  Node<T> *currHead = head;
  while(currHead != NULL){
    Node<T> *nextHead = currHead->next;
    delete currHead;
    currHead = nextHead;
  }
  Node<T> *currTail = tail;
  while(currTail != NULL){
    Node<T> *nextTail = currTail->next;
    delete currTail;
    currTail = nextTail;
  }
}
```

And for reference here's my full linkedlist queue implementation:

```
template <class T>
class Node{
public:
  T data;
  Node<T> *next=NULL;
};

template <class T>
class Queue{
public:
  Queue();
  ~Queue();
  void push(T);
  T pop();
  int size=0;
  Node<T> *head=NULL;
  Node<T> *tail=NULL;
};

template <class T>
Queue<T>::Queue(){}

template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue(){
  Node<T> *currHead = head;
  while(currHead != NULL){
    Node<T> *nextHead = currHead->next;
    delete currHead;
    currHead = nextHead;
  }
  Node<T> *currTail = tail;
  while(currTail != NULL){
    Node<T> *nextTail = currTail->next;
    delete currTail;
    currTail = nextTail;
  }
}

template <class T>
void Queue<T>::push(T data){
  Node<T> *node = new Node<T>;
  node->data = data;
  if(head == NULL){
    head = node;
  }else{
    tail->next = node;
  }
  tail = node;
  size++;
}

template <class T>
T Queue<T>::pop(){
  if(size == 0){
    throw "Empty Queue";
  }else{
    Node<T> *oldHead = head;
    T oldData = oldHead->data;
    head = head->next;
    size--;
    delete oldHead;
    return oldData;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I've also tried the following definition for the destructor but I am getting the same error:

```
template <class T>
Queue<T>::~Queue(){

  while(head != NULL){
    Node<T> *currHead = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete currHead;
  }

  while(tail != NULL){
    Node<T> *currTail = tail;
    tail = tail->next;
    delete currTail;
  }
}
```

Comment: `currHead = nextHead;` after `delete currHead;`?  You are doing similar stuff many times in your code.

Comment: What should I be doing? I am at a loss here - If you see my EDIT, I tried something different for the destructor but I am still get the "Aborted (Core Dumped)" error

Comment: not just in your destructor, even in your *full linkedlist queue implementation* you are making a similar mistake.

Comment: I've only used the delete operator one other time in the pop() method - but I don't see that I've ever reused the variable after deleting it in that method so there shouldn't be an issue right? What should be the proper implementation?

Comment: Once you have deleted the queue from the head, why delete it again from the tail?  It should be completely deleted by then.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I checked - even after deleting head, tail != NULL, so shouldnt I still need to delete it after that?

Answer (score 3):

In the first part of your destructor you're deleting all the list items starting from head. In the second part of the destructor you're attempting to delete last list item again by using its pointer kept in tail but it's already deleted in the first part.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I checked - even after deleting head in the first part of the destructor, still tail != NULL, so shouldnt I still need to delete it after that?

Comment: @mathmonkey The head and tail pointers store the same address, so `tail != NULL` will be true, even if the memory is already deleted.

Comment: This seems to be the problem but actually it is not. If this was the case then the error of _double free error_ would have generated. the problem is that the `next` pointer of last has not been defined. Hence first loop will never terminate

Comment: @AvantikaSaini Last item in the list has next=NULL because it was initialized in Node constructor and never modified

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a pointer doesn't change the pointer or any other pointers that point to the deleted memory:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* head = new int[4];
    int* tail = head;

    delete head;

    std::cout << "head = " << (void*)head << ", tail = " << (void*)tail << "\n";
}
```

What your code should be is:

```
template<typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue(){
  Node<T> *currHead = head;
  while(currHead != nullptr){
    Node<T> *nextHead = currHead->next;
    delete currHead;
    currHead = nextHead;
  }
  head = tail = nullptr;
  size = 0;
}
```

or if your pop function works:

```
template<typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue() {
    while (size)
        pop();
}
```